# Why are Cosine Similarity and TF-IDF used together?

Tags: data-mining, text-mining, tf-idf, cosine-similarity, linguistics

> `TF-IDF` and `Cosine Similarity` is a commonly used combination for
>   text clustering. Each document is represented by vectors of TF-IDF
>   weights.

This is what my text book says.

With Cosine Similarity you can then compute the similarities between those documents.

But why are exactly those techniques used together?
What is the advantage?

Could for example Jaccard Similarity also be used?

I know, *how* it works, but I want to know, *why* exactly these techniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TF-IDF is the *weighting* used.

Cosine is the *measure* used.

You could use cosine without weighting, but results then usually are worse. Jaccard works on sets - it's not obvious how to use weights without turning it into something else without making it the same as Cosine.